# sqlite error code = 1 , msg = no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using the following code, for creating database connection.but table is not getting created.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notification.db";
    public static final String Title = "Title";
    public static final String NotificationId = "NotificationId";
    public static final String Subject = "Subject";
    public static final String TABLE = "notification";
    public static final String Flag = "Flag";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
        android.util.Log.v("DatabaseHelper","Constructor called");
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        android.util.Log.v("SQLiteDatabase","SQLiteDatabase create called");
        String sql = "create table notification"  + "( " + BaseColumns._ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, "+ NotificationId + " text, " + Title + " text, " + Subject + " text, "+ Flag + " text);"
        ;
        db.execSQL(sql);


    }


}
```

this is my insert function in an other class

```
protected void insert(String notificationid,String title, String subject,String flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            eventsData = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            Log.i("insert", "inside insert");
            Log.i(TAG, "insert"+notificationid);
            Log.i(TAG, "insert"+title);
            Log.i(TAG, "insert"+subject);
            Log.i(TAG, "insert"+flag);
            SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
            android.util.Log.v("insert","SQLiteDatabase called");
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            android.util.Log.v("insert","ContentValues called");
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.NotificationId, notificationid);
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.Title, title);
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.Subject, subject);
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.Flag, flag);
            android.util.Log.v("insert","after values.put");
            db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null, values);
            Log.i("insert", "after insert");

    }
```

while inserting data i am getting error no such table found.However same code works properly if i create table notification from console shell.Can any one help me out in this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I noticed you don't have the onUpgrade implemented.  Is it possible that the first time you ran this the database was created but the table logic wasn't implemented?  Maybe try clearing the data via Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications.  Just a guess

Answer (score 1):

The onCreate method is not getting called. Make a method called say...createDatabase, and put your onCreate code in there, then call createDatabase as

```
DataBaseHelper myDataBaseHelper;
myDataBaseHelper.createDatabase();
```

onCreate is generally used with the onUpgrade method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to uninstall your app if You are making changes to your database..try uninstalling your app and reinstall it.